# How to get the rowcount of a csv file in pl-sql

Tags: plsql

I  want to read a csv file and if the file contains more than 1000 rows I have to discard it otherwise process it:

Comment: It is better to preprocess it in a shell script before loading it. A simple `if` condition comparing the output of `wc -l filename`  would help, if you're running on a unix host. Similar options would be available in windows also.

Comment: Another option is to use the CSV file as an external table. Doing so, you'd be able to check `select count(*) from the_external_table` and decide what to do next (load or discard).